# Can't scale PNG to android app SplashScreen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm implementing a loading screen on my application, I followed this tutorial:
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Pretty cool and simple, but when the loading screen is shown, the png image I use is very zoomed in, because I didn't scale it. My question is, how can I do it?
Here is the drawable xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/white"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/loading"
            />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Can you attach the image of the loading drawable, and a screenshot of what it looks like on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<item android:width="100dp"
      android:height="100dp">
      <bitmap
          android:src="@drawable/loading"/>
</item>
```